# Unity 3D Stop spawn particles after hit a wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a work for school: a game like bomberman.
My problem is when a bomb explodes, the particles should stop spawning after the wall. Here an image of the problem:

[image]

I have this code here to spawn the bomb and start the coroutine to spawn the particles in every diresction:

```
void Explode()
    {
        Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector3.forward));
        StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector3.right));
        StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector3.back));
        StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector3.left));
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        exploded = true;
        GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;
        Invoke("desativar_particulas", 0.4f);
        Destroy(gameObject, .45f);

      }
```

And here is my coroutine to spawn the particles:

```
 private IEnumerator CreateExplosions(Vector3 direction)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {

        RaycastHit hit;

        Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, .5f, 0), direction * 10, out hit, i, levelMask);

        if (!hit.collider)
        {
                Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position + (i * direction * 10), explosionPrefab.transform.rotation);
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.05f);
    }
}
```

That if statement should do the trick: the wall have a box component collider and the particle have a box collider component as a trigger.
Am I missing something? Please help, thank you.

Comment: ParticleSystems have a component for collision, you can use that to destroy them or bounce off the wall if they hit the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this:
`Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, .5f, 0), direction * 10, out hit, i, levelMask)`
It looks like you're incrementing the distance of each cast to reach the next block each time (smart move, by the way. I would have done this in a much more convoluted way.), but only going to a distance as high as 3, whereas in all the references to the location of the explosions, you've magnified it by ten.
Did you perhaps mean to do something like this:

```
Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, .5f, 0), direction, out hit, i * 10, levelMask)
```

Wherein the **direction** of the raycast is simply the direction you input to the function and the **distance** is magnified by ten?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why u instantiate multiple particle systems, instead of using one with the built in collision menu? Wasted potential...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure how the collisions work in a particle system in this submenu, doing it dynamically can be hard:

[image]